# expo typescript app how to correctly type navigation propto avoid. : "t 'navigation' implicitly has an 'any' type"

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, expo, react-navigation

I use in my expo app react-navigation and in a class component, I want to navigate to another screen ...
I get the props in a function this way :

```
     private signUp({navigation}): void {
         // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
         console.log('navigation', navigation);
       navigation.navigate('CheckSteps')
       } 
   ...
 signUp={ () => this.signUp(this.props)} />
```

But at the level of my signUp function, on the navigation I have a typing error:

**Binding element 'navigation' implicitly has an 'any' type**

How to remove this error correctly ??

Comment: @GiladShnoor that's for older version of react-navigation. If you're using react-navigation 5, and i guess you are. Then you can look up to this doc: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript/

Comment: @UğurEren ok thx for your link ;)
I have type my navigation props like the doc and no more error :
  ```private signUp({navigation} : IProps): void { ...```  
But now i have an error when ipass **this.props** in my render :

```... signUp={ () => this.signUp(this.props)} />``` 

**Argument of type 'Readonly<IStyles> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IProps'.
  Property 'navigation' is missing in type 'Readonly<IStyles> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>' but required in type 'IProps'**

Comment: Are your component props typed as `IProps`?  Sounds like you aren't requiring the `navigation` on your component's props.

Comment: Thx @LindaPaiste, I have re-typed**navigation** in **IProps** and that work ;)